# how do I do a multiply effect in adobe flash builder for a button?

Tags: air, flash-builder, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

In Adobe Photoshop or Illustrator, you can do an effect called Multiply on a layer.

Is there a way for me to do the same thing for a button in Adobe Flash Builder?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `blendMode` property of the button. This will allow you to set a variety of filters including Multiply, Overlay, Screen etc.

For a full list see [Adobe's section on Applying Blend Modes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05_Display_Programming_22.html)